# Unable to access Java class in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm new to the Robot framework.
I have installed jython and configured everything, but when I'm trying to invoke java class it's throwing an error.

I have defined few generic methods in java class named as 'Library' now I want to use these methods in robot file.

I tried below code :

1.

*** Settings ***

Library    AppiumLibrary

Library    C:\Users\Uday\Documents\Uday\qa-robot-mobileAutomation\src\test\java\Utilities\Library.java

*** Test Cases ***

Sign_in_application

2.

*** Settings ***

Library    AppiumLibrary

Library    Library.java

*** Test Cases ***

Sign_in_application

3.

*** Settings ***

Library    AppiumLibrary

Library    Utilities.Library.java

*** Test Cases ***

Sign_in_application

4.

3.

*** Settings ***

Library    AppiumLibrary

Library    Utilities.Library.java

*** Test Cases ***

Sign_in_application

Errors :

1. failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Library' (for scenario 1 & 4)
2. Test library 'Library.java' does not exist.  (for scenario 2 & 3)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an eclipse IDE, then you must add the said libraries to red.xml to allow importing those libs. You can right click on project to Auto-discover missing libraries.